# Can I use both @Post and @Get on the same method

Tags: jersey, tomcat7

I would like to use both @Post and @Get on the same method like

```
@GET
@POST
@Path("{mode}")
public void paymentFinish(@PathParam("mode") String mode, String s) {
    logger.debug("Enter PayStatus POST");
    logger.debug(mode);
}
```

Even I write like this, I got error. What I want is whatever get or post to the sameurl, the same method works. Is it possible? Now I separate two methods, one for get and one for post.

Comment: what error do you have?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unfortunately, only one should be used in order to avoid Jersey exception.
But you could do something like :

```
@GET
@Path("{mode}")
public void paymentFinish(@PathParam("mode") String mode, String s) {
    commonFunction(mode);
}

@POST
@Path("{mode}")
public void paymentFinishPOST(@PathParam("mode") String mode, String s) {
    commonFunction(mode);
}

private void commonFunction(String mode)
{
    logger.debug("Enter PayStatus POST");
    logger.debug(mode);
}
```

By doing so, if you want to change inner behavior of your functions, you will only have to change one function.

Note that method name in java for get vs post need to be different.

Comment: Yeah, currently I am using like this.

Answer (score 1):

After searching a lot trying to avoid the solution above, I found nothing....

Then I decided to create a custom annotation so I didn't have to waste time duplicating methods.

Here's the github link: [Jersey-Gest](https://github.com/rapito/Jersey-Gest)

It allows you to create GET and Post Methods on a single Annotation by generating a new class from it.

I hope it helps you the same way it helped me :)

### Edit:

If for some reason the above link stops working, here's what I did:

- Created a compile-time annotation *@RestMethod* for class methods.
- Created a compile-time annotation *@RestClass* for classes.
- Create an AnnotationProcessor which generates a new class with Jersey's corresponding annotations and for each method creates a **GET** and a **POST** method which callsback to the original method annotated with *@RestClass*.

All methods annotated with ***@RestMethod*** must be static and contained within a class annotated with ***@RestClass***.

### Example (TestService.java):

```
@RestClass(path = "/wsdl")
public class TestService
{

    @RestMethod(path = "/helloGest")
    public static String helloGest()
    {
        return "Hello Gest!";
    }

}
```

***Generates something like (TestServiceImpl.java):***

```
@Path("/wsdl")
@Produces("application/xml")
public class TestServiceImpl
{
    @GET
    @Path("/helloGest")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public String helloGestGet()
    {
        return TestService.helloGest();
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/helloGest")
    @Consumes(MediaType.WILDCARD)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public String helloGestPost()
    {
        return TestService.helloGest();
    }
}
```

Comment: Link only answers are frowned upon and often deleted because they become useless when the link changed.

Comment: @dan-neely I understand, I edited my post to explain what was it that I did in case someone wants to re-implement it then. That if for some reason I delete the repo.